# Identify Socialist Realist painting

Tags: painting

My grad school friend sent me a link to a painting that he liked; let me put the link and then an image.  Evidently painted circa 1963. We were not able to identify the artist or, for example, find an actual book  displaying   this.  There are letters in the lower left that resemble KYKOLNIK, but that could just be something to do with a website.

Oh there is a big list of artists transliterated  at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_20th-century_Russian_painters

https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_preview/2/6/6/17977662.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

> Ural artist Nina Vasilievna Kostina (1934-2021)

<sub>Source [dianov-art.ru](http://dianov-art.ru/2023/04/02/zhivopis-niny-kostinoj/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you!  Will